# Merge replication between sql server 2008 and 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, replication, merge-replication

Good day guys, I have one issue I'm trying to organise Merge replication between two servers 2000 and 2008. I tried two variants:

First: I made publication at Sql server 2000 and when I tried to made  subscription at 2008 I received following message: "For merge publications, the version of the Subscriber must not exceed the version of the Publisher".

Second one: I made publication at Sql server 2008 and when I tried to made  subscription at 2000 I received following message: "to connect this server you must use SQL server Management Studio or SQL Server Management Objects"

So could anyone give me good advice how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Set it all up using SSMS 2008: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/3e4827bc-17c7-44a2-beea-e93e03d52528/

Comment: Thank you buddy but now it says following: The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User SQLEVAL2K3-2013\Administrator.  The last step to run was step 1 (Run agent.) How can I fix that ?

Comment: That sounds like permissions, make sure that the user you are using to run the job has access to all the databases and servers you are connecting to

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Using Multiple Versions of SQL Server in a Replication Topology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx):

> For merge replication, a Subscriber to a merge publication can be any
>   version no later than the Publisher version.

This means you must make the SQL Server 2008 instance the Publisher and the SQL Server 2000 instance the Subscriber.  Use SQL Server 2008 Management Studio to configure the topology.

Comment: Sorry Man I have no enough reputation for that.